Christmas Special episode with a dad stealing a toy
I am trying to locate a Christmas episode from a TV sitcom that would have aired in America in English around the late 80's or very early 90's. The show was similar to a Married w/ Children or an Unhappily Ever After dysfunctional family comedy sitcom potentially from FOX network. I have searched descriptions from Married w/ Children or an Unhappily Ever After and haven't found the episode I'm looking for.
The episode took place around Christmas time. The family was trying to get gifts for the kids. The majority of this episode took place in a Mall. I remember the main plot point was that the Dad of the family took the Mall job as a Santa in order to steal a Caveman Toy fro the Charity Donation bin located in the center of the mall. The Donation bin was rather large and was made of plexi glass so you could see all the toys inside including this Caveman doll that the kids wanted. After hours the Dad goes to steal the doll from the charity donation bin and gets caught by the security team. 
I have been trying to find this episode for quite some time and if anybody remembers this type of plot point it would be greatly appreciated.

Sounds like the Dave's World 1st season, 2-part Xmas episode I Saw Mommy Kicking Santa Claus that aired in 1993. From TVBuzer:

Beth is frantic to find a Cannibal Caveman for Willie after he says it's the only toy he wants this year. But the stores are all sold out due to their popularity. Beth learns that there is a shipment coming on Christmas Eve and asks Dave to stop and pick one up while he shops for her gift. [...] Dave gets arrested for shoplifting [the] cannibal caveman toy from the charity bin, while Beth gives the mall Santa an earful for promising Willie his elusive present.

No clips available online, unfortunately, but maybe a picture of the cast will jog your memory:


By Jove I think you've got it! THANK YOU!!

@JackRossi No problem. :) Don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer to approve it and resolve the question.
